# ebean order by with oneToMany property with pagination

Tags: pagination, sql-order-by, one-to-many, ebean

I'm trying to get paginates orders, sorted on the cration date of the current version (currentVersion = true)

Here is the Order class :

```
@Entity
public class Offer extends Model {
    @Id   
    public Long id;
    ....
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "offer", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Version> versions; 
    ...  
}
```

Here is the version class

```
@Entity
public class Version extends Model {

    @Id   
    public Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "OFFER_ID")
    public Offer offer;
    public Boolean currentVersion = false;
    public Date creation;
    ...  
}
```

Here is the fetch code as I found on eBean documentation :

```
 Query<Offre> query = Ebean.find(Offer.class);

 List<Offer> offers = query.fetch("versions")
                               .where()
                               .eq("versions.currentVersion", true)
                               .orderBy("versions.creation desc nulls last")
                               .setFirstRow(0)
                               .setMaxRows(10)
                               .findPagedList().getList();
```

Here is the expected SQL

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT     /*+ FIRST_ROWS(10) */     rownum rn_,  a.*  FROM
    (SELECT t0.id c0,
       ... 
      t0.OPTLOCK c32
    FROM offer t0
    INNER JOIN version t1 on t0.id = t1.OFFER_ID 
    ORDER BY t1.creation
    ) a
  WHERE rownum <= 10
  ) ; --bind()
```

Here is the actual SQL

```
First one:

SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT
    /*+ FIRST_ROWS(10) */
    rownum rn_,
    a.*
  FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT t0.id c0,
      ...
      t0.id
      ...
    FROM offer t0
    JOIN versions u1  ON u1.OFFER_ID = t0.id
    WHERE u1.current_version = true
    AND u1.current_version   = true
    ORDER BY t0.id
    ) a
  WHERE rownum <= 10
  ) ; 

Second one : 

SELECT t0.OFFER_ID c0,
  t0.id c1,
  ...
  t0.creation c3,
  ...
  t0.current_version c12,
  ...
  t0.OFFER_ID c30,
  ...
FROM versions t0
WHERE (t0.OFFER_ID) IN (990,991,992,993,994,995,996,997,998,999)
ORDER BY t0.creation;
```

Question : What do I need to change to get the expected SQL ?

Thank you very much for help

Versions used : 
ebean 7.6.1 from play 2.5.14

Comment: the problems happened after migration from Play 2.4 to Play 2.5. in the previous version, setting setFirstRow(0) / setMaxRows(10) didn't implied to have a order by t0.id clause automaticly. I could do a raw SQL order By. Now it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I found a walk-around:

Instead of

```
List<Offer> offers = query.fetch("versions")
                               .where()
                               .eq("versions.currentVersion", true)
                               .orderBy("versions.creation desc nulls last")
                               .setFirstRow(0)
                               .setMaxRows(10)
                               .findPagedList().getList();
```

I've found :

```
List<Offer> offers = query.fetch("versions")
                               .where()
                               .eq("versions.currentVersion", true)
                               .orderBy("u1.creation desc") // <-- line with the change
                               .setFirstRow(0)
                               .setMaxRows(10)
                               .findPagedList().getList();
```

I make sure that the join between offer and versions is made only once and than assume that version join alias will be u1.

At least, it's doning the job.

Bye